# Convert a string containing a numeric value to the same string with different culture settings while preserving the original format

Tags: c#, .net, number-formatting, cultureinfo

I have a string that contains a numeric value in some culture (for example, the string is "$ 1000.00" and the culture is "en"). I want to convert this string to a string in the other culture while preserving as much information about the original format as possible.
For example:

`"$ 1000.00"` in "en" culture => `"1 000,00 $"` in "ru" culture.

I've tried the most obvious approach:

```
private static bool TryConvertNumberString(IFormatProvider fromFormat, IFormatProvider toFormat, string number, out string result)
{
    double numericResult;
    if (!double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Any, fromFormat, out numericResult))
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    result = numericResult.ToString(toFormat);
    return true;
}
```

But this does not work the way I want it to: double.TryParse "eats" all information about the presence of currency sign, decimal digits, etc. So if I try to use this method like this:

```
string result;
TryConvertNumberString(new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("ru"), "$ 1000.00", out result);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I'll get just `1000`, not `"1 000,00 $"`.

Is there an easy way to achieve this behavior using .NET?

Answer (score 2):

[`Double.ToString(IFormatProvider)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [the general (`"G"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GFormatString) be default and that specifier doesn't return [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwz6tx0h(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the current [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

You can just use [The `"C"` (or currency) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) as a first parameter in your `ToString` method which is exactly what you are looking for.

```
result = numericResult.ToString("C", toFormat);
```

<kbd>[`Here a demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmW3rW)</kbd>.

By the way, `ru-RU` culture has `₽` as a `CurrencySymbol`, if you want `$` in a result, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this `ru-RU` culture, set this `CurrencySymbol` property, and use *that* cloned culture in your `toFormat` part.

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)toFormat.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$";
result = numericResult.ToString("C", clone);
```